# How can I use rackPick block to seize more than one item at once? - Anylogic

Tags: anylogic

I'm developing a project with Anylogic and I have an AGV with a Kuka cobot on top of it (a sort of mechanical arm used to pick item from a shelf, in this case) which should pick some items from a rack store. I would like the cobot to pick more than one single item at once.

[The blocks I already put are shown in the picture and I thought that specifying "seize whole set at once" in the rackPick block would have helped but it did not.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kOYee.png)

Could you help me, please?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The RackPick logic is agent-centric, i.e. the items in the rack are the active entities. They, essentially "pick themselves", optionally using your robot as a help.

So if you want your robot to pick several, it is best to batch your agents together before putting them into a rack (using Batch) and then let your robot pick that batch agent. You can unbatch into the original agents afterwards.

PS: That "seize whole set at once" option is again from the agent perspective: if it would need several resources to be picked, then this option would have an effect. In your case, with only needing 1 robot, it is meaningless